# c++/eigen:compute the orthonormal basis for the null space

Tags: c++, matrix, linear-algebra, eigen, eigen3

Matlab has a function:

```
Z = null(A);
```

This MATLAB function is an orthonormal basis for the null space of A obtained
 from the singular value decomposition.

I have to convert the MATLAB code to C++ on eigen library,but I don't know how to do this.
I have tried:

```
MatrixXf m = MatrixXf::Random(3,5);
cout << "Here is the matrix m:" << endl << m << endl;
MatrixXf ker = m.fullPivLu().kernel();
cout << "Here is a matrix whose columns form a basis of the kernel of m:"
<< endl << ker << endl;
```

Output:

```
Here is the matrix m:
0.68   0.597   -0.33   0.108   -0.27
-0.211   0.823   0.536 -0.0452  0.0268
 0.566  -0.605  -0.444   0.258   0.904
Here is a matrix whose columns form a basis of the kernel of m:
-0.219   0.763
0.00335  -0.447
  0       1
  1       0
 -0.145  -0.285
```

It's not the "orthonormal" basis for the null space.

Comment: The LU factorization alone can only extract an arbitrary basis of the null space. To get an orthonormal one you need some QR decomposition or SVD.

Comment: @ggael  But I don't know how to use QR decomposition or SVD to  compute orthonormal basis for the null space...

Answer (score 1):

You can get an orthonormal basis of the null space with `CompleteOrthogonalDecomposition`:

```cpp
template <typename Number> // 'Number' can be 'double' or 'std::complex<double>'
Eigen::Matrix<Number, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> kernel_COD(
    const Eigen::Matrix<Number, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>& M) {
  Eigen::CompleteOrthogonalDecomposition<
      Eigen::Matrix<Number, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>>
      cod;
  cod.compute(M);
  unsigned rk = cod.rank();
  Eigen::Matrix<Number, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> P =
      cod.colsPermutation();
  Eigen::Matrix<Number, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> V =
      cod.matrixZ().transpose();
  Eigen::Matrix<Number, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> Kernel =
      P * V.block(0, rk, V.rows(), V.cols() - rk);
  return Kernel;
}
```